# GoBack in presentation

Tags: beamer, hyperlink, return

The problem must be ages old and there probably is an answer. I apologize that I have not located it yet.

The Problem: Return from a detour in a Beamer presentation.

If the detour is just one slide, \Acrobatmenu{GoBack} works fine but not if it is a longer detour.

So far the only solution I have found is to define different static labels to return to for every detour.

Is it possible to (re)create a label automatically so that a return-button always goes to the last used/defined label, say, "return"?

Wilhelm

Comment: You can create your own fake navigation buttons using tikzpagenodes and `\hypertarget`&`\hyperlink`.  An MWE would be useful here.

Comment: Use the alt + arrow back key on your keyboard.